# Chrome Extension: How to get user name?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Google chrome extension. For some functionality, I need user's **system login name (no password)**. By using **JavaScript**, it is not possible to do so.

Some suggest NPAPI, but I have no idea about it, so I quit.

Next thing I'm trying to get user name in **Chrome Browser**. But still no success.

I try to use some thing like:

```
var currentUser; 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) { 
  if (xhr.readyState == 1) { 
    currentUser = null; 
    if (xhr.status == 200) 
    {
      var re = new RegExp(/<b class="?gb4"?>[\s]*([^<]+@[^<]+)      <\/b>/i); 
      var m = re.exec(xhr.responseText); 
      if (m && m.length == 2) { 
        currentUser = m[1]; 
      } 
    } 
    console.log("Currently logged user (on google.com): " +   currentUser); 
  } 
}; 
xhr.open('GET', ' https://myaccount.google.com/?pli=1', false); 
xhr.send(); `
```

still no success.

My whole agenda is to get user name (either desktop login name or Chrome login name), and I'm not able to get it.

I need to send this username as parameter to my service, as user name works as primary key.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First off, you say that you need this login information to identify a user, using it as a primary key.

That automatically disqualifies system login names: **they are not unique**.

Now, let's get back to logged-in Chrome user. Google Account is reasonably unique.

There are two approaches to take here.

1. Chrome's [`chrome.identity` API can provide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) both the email and, maybe better for your purposes, a unique ID for the account.

   You will need `"identity"` and `"identity.email"` permissions. Then:

   ```
   chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo) {
    /* Use userInfo.email, or better (for privacy) userInfo.id
       They will be empty if user is not signed in in Chrome */
   });
   ```
2. An alternative approach is to use Google's OAuth on your service. Again, see the `chrome.identity` documentation.

Comment: Thank you Xan for the help, i'm using chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo as this fulfill my purpose, but while applying it i'm getting errror.
inside manifest i added permission

 **"permissions":["tabs" ,"idle","identity","identity.email"]**

and inside js file i added 

**chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo){
    console.log(userInfo);
   //console.log(userInfo.id);
});**

just to see O/P. However i'm getting error
 **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProfileUserInfo' of undefined**

What i have  to improve in code, do i need some key from google console?

Comment: What i need to Improve ? is there any thing else i need to add in manifest?

Comment: Are you trying to do it from a content script (this API is not available there)? Did you reload the extension?

Comment: Do it from background script, not content script.

Comment: sorry for late comment, the answers given by xan worked, thing is that it only work for chrome apps, i was trying it on chrome extension. Thankyou for your support, now i understand better.

Comment: I know, it should work on extension also,but for me it is working on apps,which is better. Thankyou for help.

Comment: ProfileUserInfo gives just the primary logged in email, What if i want to get the emails of all the logged in accounts, (I can have multiple accounts logged in simultaneously)

Comment: is there a way from chrome web extension I should be able to read all the user policy on the device ?

Comment: @Shubham Aggarwal you suppose to work with the current user, the current user has their extensions installed. So, it should work in that way. You shouldn't get information of a user that didn't install your extension

Answer (score 0):

Chrome.identity has a method getProfileUserInfo but it gives out the details of only primary user.

There is an alternative:

When you open chrome, you launch onto the home screen and you should be able to see a circle on the top right corner which shows image of logged in user. You can access that using DOM. Once you do that you will be able to get information about all the logged in users.

Comment: Yes. Except this is a privileged `chrome://` page that cannot be accessed by extensions.

Comment: @Xan: Oh, I didn't know about it. I had to make an extention that cycles through all the logged in gmail accounts, so for that purpose I did what i wrote and it worked fine.

Comment: It would indeed work for the gmail website DOM, but not for the New Tab page.

Comment: @Xan: Oh, Thanks a lot for telling me this!